# Single row update using primary key affects many rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, update

I'm doing a very simple datetime update in a table using its primary key:

```
update TABLE 
set END_DATE = '2015-10-14 00:00:00' 
where ID = 1165027;
```

I received the message `(1 row(s) affected)` 183 times!

When doing a select only one row is returned:

```
select * from TABLE where ID = 1165027;
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Is there an (`update`) trigger on the table?

Comment: Yes precisely @ypercube. A chain of triggers is set in motion with the "simple" update :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*<sub>As answered by [ypercube](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/993/ypercube) in a comment to the question</sub>*

There are one or more **trigger(s)** on your table.

The multiple `(1 row(s) affected)` messages are generated not just by your single-row update statement, but also by other statements in the triggers fired from that original action.